# How to evaluate Storm cluster after testing

Tags: cluster-computing, evaluation, apache-storm

I have tested Storm on 5 virtual machines on AWS ec2 but I don't know how to evaluate it after testing. in addition the the number of tuples in Topology stats does not incrementing over the time and sometimes the number reset to small number?

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. What do you want to "evaluate"? Please give more details.

Comment: I have integrated Storm with Esper and deployed them to process big data.

Comment: I need to know how many tuples the cluster has processed by using Storm  UI but UI didn't show the total number, so how I can demonstrate my system, and write the result in my dissertation ?

in addition, I tested my system with 13GB taxi trips data with 173 million events on 5 virtual machines in AWS EC2 one type m3.xlarge and four m3.large but they didn't manage the processing and some of workers stopped with problem out of memory in heap size.

Comment: Your question is way to broad... Storm UI is pretty reliable. If there are no numbers show, your setup might be incorrect. Furthermore, if you get "out of memory" exceptions, either you configuration is not correct or your topology code does something "bad". But it is too hard to tell. You should break down your question into multiple specific ones...

Comment: Storm ui gives number of tuples but don't keep increasing and after some time starting showed another number. for example, All time 14381293 tuples and after that this number was 81292 . so why over time UI does not keep increasing the number, does that normal for UI or just for me ?

Comment: Does this happens during the "out of memory" error? Maybe that is the cause. Have no other idea...

Comment: Yes, the ui reached 40 million and then counting from 2 million and , I think this because the heap size was "out of memory"

Comment: Did you figure why this numbers decrease ? How you did it and help ?

Comment: I didn't get any idea about this problem and probably the cause of problem might be " I think this because the heap size was "out of memory"